# Change background image on click does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have three buttons. I want to change background image of banner by clicking on one of the buttons. I was trying to set it up with the function that I give you below. It should take buttons by id and change the background image of class banner. What am I doing wrong ? I'm also using sass if it change something.

Here is the code:

```js
function changebackground() {
    button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('banner').style.bacgkroundImage = "url(".. / images / banner - img.png ")";
    })
    button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('banner').style.bacgkroundImage = "url(".. / images / banner - img2.png ")";
    })
    button3.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('banner').style.bacgkroundImage = "url(".. / images / banner - img3.png ")";
    })
}
```

```css
.banner {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150 ");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 570px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}


.banner .carousel {
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.banner .carousel .button {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  position: relative;
}

.banner .carousel .button .first {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fea100;
}

.banner .banner-text {
  font-family: "Playfair Display";
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  left: 15%;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 2;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="button" id="button1">
            <div class="first"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="button" id="button2">
            <div class="second"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="button" id="button3">
            <div class="third"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner-text">
        <h1>Test your fav dish</h1>
        <h2>from <span>luxury restaurent</span></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `"url(".. / images / banner - img.png ")";` is syntactically incorrect - read the errors in the console.

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. You have several typographical errors in your JS. Check your spelling of "background" and the urls.

Comment: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a HTMLCollection not an element.  [Relevant Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName#Get_the_first_element_whose_class_is_'test') (from the same page).

Comment: How should i link it in javascript ? How its supposed to be written ?

Comment: @Ludar0 I've updated my script in my answer so it uses images like your script. If you are not seeing any change with your images, check that the url of those images is correct. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are some mistakes in your code:

- You are not calling the method `changebackground` that is responsible to attach the event handlers. Without calling this method first, your event handlers will never be executed
- `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, so you have to access with `[0]` to get the `div.banner` element
- Spelling mistake `bacgkroundImage` should be `backgroundImage`
- `"url(".. / images / banner - img3.png ")"` should be `"url('.. / images / banner - img3.png ')"`

```js
function changebackground() {
    document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.getElementsByClassName('banner')[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080')";
        
    })
    button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('banner')[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF')";
    })
    button3.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('banner')[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('https://via.placeholder.com/150/FFFF00/000000')";
    })
}

changebackground();
```

```css
.banner {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150 ");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 270px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}


.banner .carousel {
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.banner .carousel .button {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  position: relative;
}

.banner .carousel .button .first {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fea100;
}

.banner .banner-text {
  font-family: "Playfair Display";
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  left: 15%;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 2;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
        <div class="carousel">
            <div class="button" id="button1">            
                <div class="first"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="button" id="button2">
                <div class="second"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="button" id="button3">
                <div class="third"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="banner-text">
            <h1>Test your fav dish</h1>
            <h2>from <span>luxury restaurent</span></h2>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `document.getElementsByClassName('banner')` returns an array, so you can't apply style property

Second, you have a syntax error in your code `"url(".. / images / banner - img.png ")"`, change to this: `"url('../images/banner-img.png')"`

To solve the first problem try this:

```
var banners = document.getElementsByClassName('banner');
//The following code needs to be inside the first click function, change it for the other two clicks
var  i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < banners.length; i++)
{
    banners[i].style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/banner-img.png')";
}
```

Finally you have to call `changebackground()` to make it works